Reading EXIF Data (Image MetaData) Fails
For years I've been reading Exif data from Images using the following code to get the individual ExifTags but recently my code has stopped working
Has anyone experienced the same issue using VB.net and knows of a solution.
Many thanks for your help
Jim
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sImg As String = "c:\temp\SomeImage.jpg"
    Dim img As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(sImg)
    Dim sMsg As String = "Property Items: " & img.PropertyItems.Count & vbCrLf

    For Each pi As PropertyItem In img.PropertyItems
        sMsg += "Property Id: " & pi.Id & vbCrLf
    Next

    MsgBox(sMsg)

End Sub

End Class
Until about a month ago this would display numerous ExifTags from which I could obtain their individual properties. Recently performing this operation no yields only 2 tags as follows for any image I've tried.
Property Items: 2
Property ID: 20625
Property ID: 20624
I've tried images from several different cameras - each showing the same 2 property items - rather than the full list. I know that the ExifTags exist in the image because I can read them using other tools, such as ExifTools or ExifLib

Just installed a Microsoft update and all working again.
